# Send email grouped on a commerce line items field

Tags: commerce, rules

I use commerce a little different than most as I schedule trips as custom line items.

A trip is scheduled by someone else and they can schedule as many trips as they want for however many users they want.

I am trying to send an email to the user that had a trip scheduled.

My problem is that a user can have multiple legs (line items) on a single order.  So when I try to loop through the line items, it sends out an email per line item (which it should) but to the user it is a duplicate.

I want to use rules to send an email out once.

Is there a way to group the line items on the user as a result and then just send one email out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution to this.  I should be able to load the list of line item entities using VBO and a view grouped on the user.  I got the information needed from here:

http://nodeone.se/sv/node/777

Then I just pass the [commerce-order:order-id] as an argument.

**EDIT**
This worked for me.